# Focus on input after hidden is set as false

Tags: html, jquery, angular, typescript

So I am trying to focus on the `input` after clicking on edit `button`. The `edit` will set `hidden` as false. For that I tried the following code

```js
editMyLink(i, currentState) {
    if (currentState == 'noEdit') {
      this.myLinkBody[i].value = this.myLinkBodyOriginal[i].value
      this.myLinkBody[i].currentState = 'edit';
      this.myLinkBody[i].buttonClass = "editButton"
    }
    else {
      this.myLinkBody[i].currentState = 'noEdit';
      this.myLinkBody[i].buttonClass = "noEditButton"
      let selector = '.myLinkEditInput:eq(' + i + ')'
      $(selector).focus()
    }
  }
```

```html
<span *ngFor="let body of myLinkBody;let i=index;let last=last;" class="myLinkBody" [class.myLinkBodyLast]="last">
  
  <input class="myLinkEditInput" type="text" (keydown.enter)="saveMyLink(i)" [hidden]="body.currentState=='edit'" [(ngModel)]="body.value"/>
  
  <a [hidden]="body.currentState=='noEdit'"[href]="domainURL+body.href">{{body.value}}</a>
  
  <div id="editLinkButton"><a [class]="body.buttonClass" (click)="editMyLink(i,body.currentState)"></a></div>
  
  <div id="deleteLinkButton"><a (click)="deleteMyLink(i)"></a></div>

</span>
```

I realised that the `hidden` will change to true only after the function has been executed so my logic to focus on the input won't work. Is there a way to focus on the input

[image]

[image: On click of edit button the cursor should focus on the input field]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need "give a breath" to Angular -first Angular must show the input, and after you focus it- So you use setTimeout. In Angular, instead of using jQuery to get selector you can use a template reference variable, so

```
<input #valueID ... [hidden]="body.currentState=='edit'" [(ngModel)]="body.value"/>
  ...
<!--see you pass the reference variable-->
<a [class]="body.buttonClass" (click)="editMyLink(i,valueID,body.currentState)"></a>
..

editMyLink(i,editID currentState) {
    if (currentState == 'noEdit') {
      this.myLinkBody[i].value = this.myLinkBodyOriginal[i].value
      this.myLinkBody[i].currentState = 'edit';
      this.myLinkBody[i].buttonClass = "editButton"
    }
    else {
      this.myLinkBody[i].currentState = 'noEdit';
      this.myLinkBody[i].buttonClass = "noEditButton"
      //here the "breath", well, the setTimeout
      setTimeout(()=>{
         editID.nativeElement.focus()
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes it worked. But before I used a `while` loop  `while(selector[0].hidden){}` before selector. It didn't work and the page hanged as it was an infinite loop. Why so?

Comment: Sorry, I can not see the "while". Anyway, if you want to only edit one field each time, I suggest you use an auxiliar variable (e.g. indexSelected) that you equal to the "index", not a property of "body" (at first equal to -1)